# my bot doesn't takes mp3 file as input which I want to convert to text?

Tags: discord, discord.py

I want to make a discord bot that I want to take an mp3 file with a command (that's in the chat or the user can give it to me using a slash command) let's say /transcribe. with it, it send the mp3 file to whisper speech to text and give back response but I my slash command do not take any attachments with it. even if it works as a reference messages it's good. here's my code

```py
class Transcribe(commands.Cog, name="transcribe"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.hybrid_command(
        name="transcribe",
        description="This is a testing command that does nothing.",
    )
    # This will only allow non-blacklisted members to execute the command
    @checks.not_blacklisted()
    # This will only allow owners of the bot to execute the command -> config.json
    @checks.is_owner()
    async def transcribe(self, ctx):
        # Check if the message has an attachment
        if not ctx.message.attachments:
            await ctx.send("Please attach an mp3 file.")
            return

        # Get the attachment url
        attachment_url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url

        # Download the file
        async with self.bot.session.get(attachment_url) as response:
            if response.status != 200:
                await ctx.send("Failed to download the file.")
                return
            content = await response.read()

        # Transcribe the audio using OpenAI
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="davinci",
            prompt=f"Transcribe the following audio: {attachment_url}",
            audio=content,
            max_tokens=1024,
            temperature=0.5,
        )

        # Send the transcription back to the user
        transcription = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        if transcription:
            await ctx.send(f"Transcription: {transcription}")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, I couldn't transcribe the audio.")
```

I want a work around or a best possible way to take mp3 from user and send it to whisper api and convert it to text. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

To receive attachments in your command, specify parameters of type [discord.Attachement](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#attachment):

```py
class Transcribe(commands.Cog, name="transcribe"):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.hybrid_command(name="transcribe")
    # This will only allow non-blacklisted members to execute the command
    @checks.not_blacklisted()
    # This will only allow owners of the bot to execute the command -> config.json
    @checks.is_owner()
    async def transcribe(self, ctx: commands.Context, audio_file: discord.Attachement):
        """This command transcribes audio files
       
        Args:
            audio_file: the audio you want to transcribe
        """
        content = await audio_file.read()

        # Transcribe the audio using OpenAI
        response = openai.Completion.create(
            engine="davinci",
            prompt=f"Transcribe the following audio: {attachment_url}",
            audio=content,
            max_tokens=1024,
            temperature=0.5,
        )

        # Send the transcription back to the user
        transcription = response.choices[0].text.strip()
        if transcription:
            await ctx.send(f"Transcription: {transcription}")
        else:
            await ctx.send("Sorry, I couldn't transcribe the audio.")
```

> - I used the [Attachement.read](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Attachment.read) method provided by the library to download the audio content directly;
> - I'm using [docstrings](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html#discord.app_commands.describe) to describe the function of the command and arguments. These descriptions will automatically be used by the application command;